# Keep sharp edges with Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I would like to keep the angle 90 in the area indicated as I apply the subdivision surface modifier on the object. I appreciate help.
[image: Sample]

Comment: I'm sorry for duplicity. I delete this post?

Comment: not at all. It just means that there is possibly an answer that can help you solve your issue. Duplicates are not a bad thing, they actually help others find information. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Also note the option to change subdivision type from Catmull-Clark to Simple. Catmull-Clark rounds edges while Simple simply subdivides geometry (similarly to the subdivide function in edit mode).

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50018/hard-edges-in-cylindrical-shape Add hard edges to your mesh

Comment: Thanks all. Solved through the link above. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50018/hard-edges-in-cylindrical-shape